# how do I load a program I have downloaded!

Tags: programming, python-2.7

I'm trying to start programming and am sure I have downloaded python.

how do I find and run this program?

Comment: python is installed by default in Ubuntu, no need to download it...

Comment: What kind of program have you downloaded? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Python is more of a programming language than a program itself but it does have an interactive shell too. Here are your main options.

#### 1. Interactive Shell

For playing around in Python, you can just run `python` and get going. Nothing is saved
Open a terminal and run `python`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Jul  5 2013, 08:21:57) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> add = lambda a, b: '%d + %d = %d' % (a, b, a+b)
>>> add(3, 72)
'3 + 72 = 75'
```

#### 2. As an interpreter

If you want to work out of a file you can. You can call it whatever you like and then just run:

```
python mypythonfile.py
```

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to exit.

#### 3. As a general purpose script

If you want your file to run like a command and you don't want to prepend `python` onto it each time, you can add a shebang at the beginning of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

... save that, and then in a terminal set the permissions

```
chmod +x mypythonfile.py
```

... and run it

```
./mypythonfile.py
```